# jquery plugin not working - TypeError 'Undefined is not a function' in safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using a jquery treeview plugin to make a list in to hierarchy view. This works fine in firefox, but results in a error like 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' in safari and 'Uncaught TypeEror : Object [object object] has no method 'treeview' in chrome error console.

Here is the code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link type="text/css" href="./methodeditor4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="../../css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./treeview/jquery.treeview.js"></script>    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./treeview/jquery.treeview.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />







<title>Method editor</title>
<script>


$(function() {

        getmethodgroups();

});



function getmethodgroups(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "listmethods.php",
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
        var methgroups = JSON.parse(data);
        for ( var i=0; i < methgroups.length; i++ ) {
            $(".list").append("<li  class=\"mgclick filetree\" id=" + methgroups[i] + "><span class=folder>" + methgroups[i] + "</span><ul></ul>" );
            $(".list").append("</li>");
            };
        $("#list").treeview({
           collapsed: true
        });
        }
    });




}
</script>
</head>

<body > 

( has all the elements )
</body>
</html>
```

The treeview plugin's script is loaded in the page and the path is correct. The same happens  with some of other plugins like tabs. Firefox is working fine, the problem is with safari and chrome. Any clues?

Thanks,
Srini.

Comment: I see #list and you are appending to .list - I don't see the full code.

Can you host the code in some url to test and give you the solution.

Comment: Hi,  Sorry about the confusion. The element has the same class and id name.

Comment: You shouldn't append the closing `</li>` separately.  Just do it all in one `append` call.

Answer (score 0):

## onReady Change

```
$(function() {
//add this
 $("#list").treeview();
        getmethodgroups();
});
```

## Script Change#

```
 var branches = "";
for ( var i=0; i < methgroups.length; i++ ) {
   branches = branches + "<li  class=\"mgclick filetree\" id=" + methgroups[i] + "><span class=folder>" + methgroups[i] + "</span><ul></ul></li>"
                };
        $(branches).appendTo("#list");
            $("#list").treeview({
               add: branches
            });
```

---

## html

```
<body>
  <ul id="#list" class="filetree">
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I think i found your version of treeview, altered my code to match that implementation.